# I need to check if a row exists where several conditions are met in a range

Tags: excel, vba

thank you for taking the time to read this post I am close to bitterly crying in a corner.

I have used VBA to produce a list of values on a sheet and now need to populate a third column with true or false based on the existence of a row in a range where several conditions are met.
in SQL this would be simple but I am a noob when it comes to VBA and can't seem to find an answer out there.

any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried already?

There are several ways to tackle branching and tests- If Then statements, Case, loops... you can usually combine them to tackle multiple conditions, either through nesting or AND statements.

Read through the references below:

http://www.excelfunctions.net/VBA-Conditional-Statements.html

http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if_then.php

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251599.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278454.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the size of your dataset you may find that Array Formulas could provide a solution. It may be more comfortable to someone who uses SQL.

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/arrayformulas.aspx

For larger datasets perhaps the IFS excel function which can resolve an expression with multiple conditions.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I ended up going with  nested ifs.
I really appreciate the assistance.